# OS X 10.6.8 - Is there any way to create a keyboard shortcut that creates a numbered list in TextEdit?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textedit

Title pretty much says it all. I'd have thought it would be a pretty simple matter, but searching the web for AppleScript and Automator-based solutions has come up empty. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!